# Compare accuracy of different models

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a way to plot the accuracy of different ML models such as

```
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

I have used this code, but not able to get a bar graph

```
#Evaluating performance
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    results.append(cv_results.mean())
    print(msg)

plt.plot(cv_results) plots a line graph
```

I am trying to plot  a bar graph with X-Axis (Different model) Y-Axis (Accuracies)

Comment: So basically you want to plot a bar chart with model names from names on the X axis and the average accuracy score from results on the Y axis?

Comment: Yes, I want to plot a bar graph to compare accuracies

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot` will plot lines as you noticed. What you need is `plt.bar` which will plot a barplot. Provided the names of the models are stored in a list `names` and the accuracies in a list `results` like in your code snippet, this should do:

```
plt.bar(names,results)
```

Comment: `ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 6 or scalar` I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you checked if names and results are both lists of the same length? If you have names = ['modelA', 'modelB'] and results = [0.78, 0.89], it will work. According to your code, I would expect your data to have this shape